# Integrate video inside Lottie

Tags: json, lottie

I'm trying to replace an image with a video by manipulating the Lottie JSON code.

Is it possible to integrate an MP4 inside a Lottie JSON code?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, this is not possible. Lottie only supports png sequences as "video" format.